# How to convert wav to mp3 and mp3 to wav while keeping the same size

Tags: mp3, wav, restore, ogg, audio-converter

I cannot find out how I can convert a wav to mp3 and mp3 to wav. Does anyone know how to convert a **.wav** file into a **.mp3** or **.ogg** **and later convert back into .wav** *while matching 100% same size like untouched* (if it can be done in the command line its much better). I tried to use LAME and later back to .wav with some tools but the file wouldn’t match 100% byte per byte like if it was never was touched. Does anyone know any command line in SoX or FFMPEG that can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most WAV files are raw PCM.  MP3 is MP3.  And, most Ogg files are going to contain Vorbis or Opus.

MP3, Vorbis, and Opus, are all **lossy codecs**.  They work by taking advantage of what we hear and what we don't hear, psychoacoustics and all that, and saving bandwidth.  It's tradeoff between bandwidth and audio quality.

You cannot use the output of a lossy codec to get back to the original source.  Therefore, you definitely can't expect to binary compare the outputs and get them to be the same.

You also can't even get the same file size really without knowing more about the source.  For instance, the input of your MP3 codec might have been 24-bit audio, but the output of the receiving codec is almost always going to be configured for 16-bit.  Also, it's common for these lossy codecs to not be sample-accurate.  MP3 in particular has a problem with this.  Read up on "gapless playback" if you're in doubt.